# ui bootstrap modal not closing on clicking on backdrop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on upgrading ruby/rails and angularjs app from 1.5 to 1.6.10 (I know its too old and we should go to latest angular, but can't right now), the issue I'm having is,

with angularjs 1.5, we're using `angular-ui/bootstrap-bower` 0.6 and the backdrop template had a click handler with this code `ng-click=\"close($event)\"` but in the latest `angular-ui/bootstrap-bower` there is no template for the backdrop and I can't figure out how to make that work.

I've got it to work by adding a global click handler in app.js to listen for click event on `.modal-backdrop` and use the `$uibModalStack.dismissAll('close')` method, is this the correct way or is there a better or more angularjs way of letting the modalinstance take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. Even if the library supported it, it would have done the same imho.
However, if you want to close only the topmost modal, you can do it as follows:

```
$uibModalStack.dismiss($uibModalStack.getTop().key);
```